# Required a regular expression which except only AlphaNumeric _-(). and space in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Hi I am novice in regex please help me on it:
i've tried below but its failing (browser is ie9)

```
<html>
<head>


<script language="JavaScript">
function myf(){
alert(document.forms["Home"]["ww"].value);
var f=document.forms["Home"]["ww"].value;
var patt = new RegExp("[A-Z]a-z0-9().,-]");
if(patt.test(document.forms["Home"]["ww"].value))
alert(10);
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<form method="" action=""  name="Home">
<input type="text" name="ww" value="123" onblur="myf()" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The "]" after the "Z" is going to mess it up.  You can test in console.  The best way to start with regular expressions when you're learning is to build them up one item at a time - make it match letters, then letters and numbers, etc., testing at each point along the way.

Comment: What do you want to allow? Add some letters other than the code in your question body.

Comment: "which except only AlphaNumeric _-(). and space in " its there in the question body..thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by `except`? not to allow?

Comment: @AvinashRaj this is second time I'm seeing someone reply to you like that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your expression:

`/^[A-Za-z0-9().,-]+$/g`

or

`var patt = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9().,-]+$");`

You want to check if entire string from the beginning to the end contains only allowed characters.

Comment: already tried not working for numeric values.

Comment: http://regexr.com/39nm5

Answer (score 0):

Change your `patt` to if you want to match only them, or add a `^` before `\w` which will negate the class.

```
var patt = /^[\w(),.\s-]+$/g
```

Comment: Sorry /[\w(),.-]/g its not working

Comment: @NaveenPandey what do you want? Do you want to allow them or not?

Comment: only - AlphaNumeric _-(). and space should be there..if anything else is there it should not except

Comment: try `var patt = /[\w(),.\s-]+/g`

Comment: Not working (its failing for alphanumeric i gave 123 as an input)

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/iS5nU8/1

Comment: Thatnks it worked ..i did a silly typing mistake...thanks everyone for your help.